# I cant get libcurl perform to work properly in a especific url

Tags: libcurl

Im am working with libcurl on Visual Studio 2017 to get an request from a google url but the program crashes without call the exception that is trapped. I´ve tested with 2 others urls and it worked fine. The google url is:
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=-23.64737184441803,-46.624&key=AIza...."

When I execute perform the code breaks without been catch by the exception:

the code is:

```
std::stringstream get_response(std::string_view url)
{
   std::stringstream str;
   curl::curl_ios<std::stringstream> writer(str);

   curl::curl_easy easy(writer);

   easy.add<CURLOPT_URL>(url.data());
   easy.add<CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION>(1L);
   easy.add<CURLOPT_VERBOSE>(1L);

   try
   {
     easy.perform();
   }
   catch (curl::curl_easy_exception error)
   {
      auto errors = error.get_traceback();
      error.print_traceback();
   }

   return str;
}
```

I´ve looked at several sites without success.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I got a little more information from the log:

```
...
schannel: SSL/TLS connection with maps.googleapis.com port 443 (step 2/3)
schannel: encrypted data got 778
schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 3542 length 4096
schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092013) -The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline.
Marked for [closure]: Failed HTTPS connection
....
```

how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I did curl_easy_setopt(&easy, CURLOPT_PROXY_SSL_OPTIONS, CURLSSLOPT_ALLOW_BEAST |  CURLSSLOPT_NO_REVOKE) but the error still remains